# Set textwidth on hg commit messages?

Tags: vim, mercurial

I use `vim` to write my Mercurial commit messages and I would like it to automatically wrap my text when it hits a specific limit, say 80 characters. My `git` setup already does this, but I'm not sure how to make `hg` behave in the same way.

How do you set the `textwidth` used in `vim` when writing `hg commit` messages?

Answer (score 4):

You can define the command to run when you do a commit by setting the `editor` option inside the `[ui]` section of your `.hgrc` config file. To set the `textwidth` in `vim` you could do:

```
[ui]
...
editor = vim -c ":set textwidth=80"
```

Answer (score 4):

Vim should already recognize hg commit messages. To set specific options for that filetype, create a file `$HOME/.vim/after/ftplugin/hgcommit.vim` (create non-existing directories) and set your option there:

```
setlocal textwidth=80
```

Then Vim should pick up your new settings, provided that your .vimrc enables filetype plugins by e.g. `filetype plugin on` or similar.

See also the faq [Question 26.3](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.3) and [Question 26.6](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.6)

Comment: This is true of version 7.4. The `hgcommit.vim` file was added during the 7.3.x series. It is not present in earlier versions.

Comment: Indeed. But you can then still create this filetype manually, e.g. add a line like this to your .vimrc: `au BufNewFile,BufRead hg-editor-*.txt           setf hgcommit` and then the rest applies as said. See also the faq [Question 26.8](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.8)

Answer (score 0):

I like to enable spell check and set my text width to 72 for hg commit messages.

Modify your `.vimrc` file to include a line like the following:

`autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead hg-editor-*.txt setlocal spell textwidth=72`

This works with pre-7.4 versions of Vim (I'm currently on 7.2).

Answer (score 0):

Most modern Vim installations will know about the `hgcommit` filetype. In that case, you can simply add the following to your .vimrc file:

```
autocmd Filetype hgcommit setlocal textwidth=72
```

---

#### Note

This solution supports other Vim settings as well. For example, I use the following line, which also turns on spellchecking:

```
autocmd Filetype hgcommit setlocal spell textwidth=72
```